# How should I release my notes under public domain if they contain quotes from proprietary texts?

Tags: publishing, public-domain, writing

I'm keeping a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/aleksandar-todorovic/notes/) that contains my personal notes. While I feel comfortable with releasing most of the things in the public domain, that repository does contain some quotes, mostly from the books I liked ([random example](https://github.com/aleksandar-todorovic/notes/blob/master/quotes/04_digital-vertigo.md)), that might be considered as proprietary.

Even though I'm well aware that I could re-use these quotes (since they're just a sentence or two long) under fair use, I'm not sure if releasing them under public domain is a copyright infringement or not. If it is, what can I do to exclude the files containing the quotes from the license?

Comment: "Fair Use" is complicated, and length of material used is only partly related to it - in that you should use only an amount of the original that is reasonable to achieve your goals - mainly the goals/purpose of your work needs to be something compatible with fair use. I don't know the status of short quotes in general, but in cases of reported sayings by real people (as opposed to quotes pulled from fiction), then you can re-type them from source (effectively you are reporting them) so you are OK provided you don't just cut&paste.

Comment: Related from Law.SE: [Can I release someone else's work under creative commons or some other license, if its fair use?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6564/can-i-release-someone-elses-work-under-creative-commons-or-some-other-license)

Comment: Without a specific FLOSS license I don't think this is on-topic - it is really a general law question, and should be migrated to [law.se].

Comment: Related question for (Creative Commons) licenses: [Do I have to exclude quotations in the license notice?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1005/138)

Comment: @curiousdannii The question says "public domain", and instruments to put a work in PD, such as CC0,  can be viewed as licenses.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would always keep detailed pointers to the origin of any third-party content and their license and author details.

Whether or not fair use applies, you are not licensing the third-party quotes IMHO, but your aggregate collections of notes and your original content as well as its organization which in itself is an original copyrightable work IMHO

/IANAL /TINLA